# UPDATE now getting no errors and 'success' but still no image in the data base. Updated code below

Tags: php

updated code and it's now displaying success but still no image in my database.
anyone have any idea why the image isnt being inserted?

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
?>


<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  if (getimagesize($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'])==FALSE) {
      echo "failed";
  } else {
      $name=addslashes($_FILES['Image']['name']);
      $image=base64_encode(file_get_contents(addslashes($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'])));
      saveimage($name,$image);
  }
} else {
    echo "error";
}

function saveimage($name,$image) {
    $con = mysqli_connect('', '','', '');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO items ('image', 'Description') VALUES ($name, $image)";
    $query=!mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if ($query) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "Not uploaded";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you please check if `$_FILES['Image']['Description']` exist? Oh, and just to be sure, is the `Image` in `$_FILES['Image']` correct?

Answer (score 1):

I have Found the issue 
Please update your query using  i have given

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO items (image, Description) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$image."')";
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check you image column datatype in database table this should be text or blob type.